# CMSampleBuffer Scaling

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I am writing an iOS app which is about live object detection. And I need to resize (scale)the video input and use the Metal framework afterwards. But I didn't find any Api provided by apple to do such thing.

I can crop it but scaling it seems harder.

Does anyone know how to do it?